# How to Pass Matrix into "Function"

Tags: function, maps, ti-basic

I'm making a TI-BASIC game, where the player can move around 2-D maps on the home screen. I make an 8x16 matrix for each map:

```
    [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
     [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

...and this "function" to display it:

```
    For(A,1,8)
    For(B,1,16)
    Output(A,B,sub(" I",[A](C,D)+1,1))
    End:End
```

Now, I have multiple maps (matrices) and need to "call" that function with a different matrix without re-typing that code every time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is possible to pass an argument to a method using the `Ans` variable.** Here is an example (with `prgmDISPLAY` based on your given display function):

```
prgmDISPLAY
For(A,1,8
For(B,1,16
Output(A,B,sub(" I",Ans(C,D)+1,1
End
End
```

You would then call this method by calling `prgmDISPLAY` from the main program, like so:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1][1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1][1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1][1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1][1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1][1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1][1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1][1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
prgmDISPLAY
```

Or, if the matrix is stored in `[A]`, simply do:

```
[A]
prgmDISPLAY
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware that `Ans` could be used across programs, and using it in a subprogram is a great solution, especially because `Lbl` and `Goto` can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TI-84 doesn't have methods.

I think your best bet is creating another program with only that "function" in it and executing that "subprogram" inside your main program whenever you need it, which is the closest thing you can get to calling a method. You could also mess around with the `Lbl` and `Goto` command, but it can be trickier (and slower) to use with larger programs.